# TFS GetService in Outlook add-in run once

Tags: c#, tfs, outlook

I want to attach a message from outlook in TFS workitem, so I created a small add-in in outlook to attach a message to workitem.
every thing is work fine, but it's work just once.
when i want to attach a message to a workitem, i've open a window form and select the workitem and attach the message. even though when the form closed it's wont be open again. 
i check every thing and i found the problem : when i use  tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService(); the form wont be open again.

also I tried to put GetService in the startup, the Click event of button wont work.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TeamConfigurations = new Configuration();
        _inspectors = Application.Inspectors;
        TeamConfigurations.TempFolder = @"C:\EntekhabTfsOutlook\";
        LoadSetting();
        CheckTempFolder();
        AddMenuBar();
    }
```

and the click event

```
   private void AddMailToAttachment_Click(CommandBarButton ctrl, ref bool cancelDefault)
    {

        var explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();
        var selection = explorer.Selection;

        var frm = new FrmWorkItemSelector(selection);
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

and finally

```
   var tfsTeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(url))
        {
            ClientCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(true)
        };
        var workService = tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

i couldn't find the problem.

p.s: i don't want to use another add-in like http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamlook/features/microsoft-outlook-integration.aspx Or another 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not related to tfs
I chnage the Create toolbar method , it's work 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268864(v=vs.90).aspx